# JS replace every second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

My code:

```
variable = '<td>some text</td><td>some text2</td><td>some text3</td><td>some text4</td><td>some text5</td><td>some text6</td>';
```

I want to replace every second `<td>` to  `</tr><tr><td>`

the new code should look like this:

```
variable1 ='<td>some text</td><td>some text2</td></tr><tr><td>some text3</td><td>some text4</td></tr><tr><td>some text5</td><td>some text6</td></tr><tr>';
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: The code shown doesn't matches the description. `Second`?

Comment: Update your question...its not described as per your requirements..

Comment: you mean modifying existing HTML via JS or?

Comment: I want to create a table,  2 columns per row, I have the same <td> and I want to add <tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex`:

```
var variable = '<td>some text</td><td>some text2</td><td>some text3</td><td>some text4</td><td>some text5</td><td>some text6</td>';

var reg = /(<td>.*?<\/td><td>.*?)<\/td>/g;

alert(variable.replace(reg, '$1</tr><tr>'));
```

1. `()`: Matching group. Used as `$1` in replace second param
2. `.*?`: Matches anything
3. `g`: Global flag to match any no. of times

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/34j7mbnz/

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$('</tr><tr>').insertAfter($('td:even'));
```

Answer (score -2):

For modifing HTML Try this code

```
<script>
$( "<td>" ).replaceAll( "</tr><tr></td>" );
</script>
```